# Can I bypass the skip parameter in Microsoft's Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a small set of data (<200 results) to retrieve using the Graph API. I am sending a post request, but all the data is not being retrieved. It seems to me that I have to use the skip parameter to constantly retrieve the next set of data.

For example, if "top":"50" and "skip":"0", then the first 50 results are retrieved.

```
{
...
"skip":"0"
"top":"50"
...
}
```

Next, I would have to update the skip parameter to 50, which would retrieve the next 50 results.

```
{
...
"skip":"50"
"top":"50"
...
}
```

Is there anyway I can bypass paging since I only need to retrieve 200 results? I've tried setting "top" to 200, but it doesn't seem to retrieve all the data.

Comment: Could you share more details? Which endpoint do you call? The behavior can differ  based on the endpoint you are calling.